# Get entity subclass without instanceOf

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, hierarchy

I have a scenario where I have a entity hierarchy structure implemented in hibernate.
It is InheritanceType.JOINED

Parent class:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "LOY") 
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Loy implements Serializable
```

Child class boundary

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "LOY_BOUNDARY") 
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID")
public class LoyBoundary implements Serializable
```

Child class percentage

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "LOY_PERCENTAGE") 
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID")
public class LoyPercentage implements Serializable
```

I have a **Customer entity class** which is **linked** to the **Loy entity class** in a  **@ManyToOne**.
The Customer can only be linked to one Loy at a time.

What I want to achieve is that I want to **query the Customer class** with unique id (passport number) and then **get The Loy for the specific Customer** through the @ManyToOne mapping in the Customer entity.

The problem that I'm sitting with is that I do not know which subclass of Loy is linked to the Customer.

1. I can go instanceOf to get the specific subclass but I want to try and avoid it.
2. I can also add a visitor pattern in the subclass entity, but not sure if this is best practice.

Comment: But what exactly Customer want to do with Loy ?

Comment: @chris Loy contains fields/columns that Customer needs to use down the line, but the fields/columns is different for every subclass of Loy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a visitor. Using `instanceof` won't work if the `ManyToOne` is lazy-loaded, because the actual type of the Loy won't be any of your subclasses, but a Hibernate proxy extending the Loy class. Indeed, Hibernate has no way to know, from the ID of the loy in the customer, which kind of Loy it refers to.

And a visitor is more OO and cleaner anyway.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I also came across a article using the visitor pattern in hibernate: Here is the [link](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/use-visitor-pattern-visit). For me it sounded like the right answer but wanted more input from the community.